# ListView does not work in AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rss

In the code below, the list view does not show the text getting from RSS Feed:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://appline.ir/index.php/android.feed?limitstart=");
        new Connect(url).execute();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private class Connect extends AsyncTask <Void, String, String>
{

    URL url;
    ProgressDialog diao;
    Connect(URL url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        diao.hide();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        diao = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        diao.setMessage("connecting...");
        diao.setIndeterminate(true);
        diao.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        try
        {
            XmlPullParserFactory parser =XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xml = parser.newPullParser();
            URL url = new URL("http://appline.ir/index.php/android.feed?limitstart=");
            XmlParser p = new XmlParser(url);
            tags = p.parse();
            InputStream input = url.openStream();
            xml.setInput(input,null);
            int event;
            String text = null;
            try {
                event = xml.getEventType();
                while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    String name=xml.getName();
                    switch (event)
                    {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = xml.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(name.equals("title")){
                            values.add(text);
                        }
                        else if(name.equals("link")){   
                            //                        link = text;
                        }
                        else if(name.equals("description")){
                            //                        description = text;
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                        break;
                    }        
                    event = xml.next(); 
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        return null;

    }

}
}
```

but when I put Xml parsing part into the `MainActivity` (using `StrictMode`), the list shows the text properly.
I cannot find the problem. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Why your doInBackground method return null and not the values ?

Comment: @SoothSayer the return value is not important in `doInBackground` method

Comment: You can't do this...`values.add(text);`. You're declaring your values `ArrayList` as an instance field of your `Activity` and you can't touch anything on the main thread from `doInBackground`. Maintain an `ArrayList` in your `AsyncTask`, add the values to that and then copy it out to your `Activity` values `ArrayList` in `onPostExecute` before calling `setListAdapter`.

Comment: @Squonk the problem is that it does not execute `onPostExecute`, because the `ProgressDialog` never hides.

Comment: @Branky : Check logcat - you'll almost certainly see that you're getting an exception as a result of trying to call `values.add(text)` in `doInBackground`. The result will be the worker thread running `doInBackground` will crash and that's the reason why `onPostExecute` is never called. Also, on an aside (possibly related) *NEVER* use empty `catch` blocks - at least use `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: @Squonk tanx for the tip about catch block ;) the logcat does not show any exception

Answer (score 1):

You must call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter` and you must call it in your UI main thread

Comment: There's no need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` when you set an `Adapter` on a `ListView`.

Comment: @SoothSayer : It doesn't matter - calling `notifyDataSetChanged` immediately after setting an `Adapter` on an `AdapterView` is totally unnecessary and won't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Yes sorry I'm wrong there's no need of calling notifyDataSetChanged(). In declaring **values** you forgot to write String inside <>

Comment: @Tiko java 7 new feature!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the adapter object to a variable and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: There's no need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` when you set an `Adapter` on a `ListView`.